# Stalled HTTP Requests in chrome

Tags: angular, ionic3, couchdb, pouchdb

I am building an ionic3 app that's supposed to work online only with CouchDB as the database. When used with PouchDB as a client database, the app works just fine. But because of the nature of the App, I would like to bypass the PouchDB and interact directly with CouchDB.

When I use PouchDB as an Interface to CouchDB in trying to maintain my code structure, I end up with a lot of Stalled Http Requests, and this only happens in chrome and when I build for android, and I guess the latter happens because android uses chrome as the app browser.
[image: Stalled request in chrome dev tools]

In my search, I found that this is the behavior of chrome when you use the same HTTP request more than once, but I can not avoid this in my app as I pull transaction data from CouchDB. In other solutions, people added extra headers to the HTTP request of which I have failed to emulate with PouchDB as a CouchDB interface.

My Connection with additional headers commented out as they did not work:

```
this.remoteDb = new PouchDB('MyRemoteConnectionString', {
            fetch(url, opts) {
             // opts.credentials = 'include';
              // opts.headers.set('Cache-Control', 'no-store');
              return PouchDB.fetch(url, opts);
            },
            skip_setup: true,
          } as any);
```

The similar solution seemed to have worked well with PouchDB > 7.0, I am using the latest PouchDB. My question is: Is there anyone out there who has managed to add headers to latest PouchDB connection and solved this issue or is there any other better library I could use to interact with CouchDB Database directly from Ionic3 App or Angular?